# Internal Server Error when adding trailing slash to URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

When going to my PHP website hosted on apache server at example.com/rail/basic/ , the browser displays error 500 internal server error.
However when removing the trailing slash in the url, such as example.com/rail/basic, the page loads fine.
My website is PHP and the below htaccess is inside the /rail/ directory. 
The bottom few lines of code are to remove the .php file extension for look and feel purposes.
I'd be grateful if anyone could explain how I should edit my Htaccess file, so that the URL works both WITH and WITHOUT a trailing slash?
Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rail/
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.php
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php/ [L]
```

Comment: If you requested `/rail/basic/`, then what do you think `%{REQUEST_URI}.php/` will result in …?

Comment: Evidently not what I was hoping for, as it still gives error 500 with trailing slash

Comment: What about this? https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=1ebd2ed8-a7f6-598d-94e7-e5233e0e38d9

Comment: Well the first thing you do on a 500 Internal Server Error should be to check the server’s log files, to find out what the error actually was.

Comment: _“Evidently not what I was hoping for”_ - what _were_ you hoping for, that your server is able to find a file named `rail/basic/.php/` somewhere in the file system?

Comment: This is the only error in the apache error log file that relates to the matter at hand

[Fri Oct 19 12:50:22.603152 2018] [rewrite:warn] [pid 2245] AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored. (/var/www/html/rail/.htaccess:8)
-

Comment: @HerrSerker that snippet doesn't work, it just redirects user to /1 in the address bar with 404 not found

Comment: @trainmania100 You did use a backward slash `\` in front of the `1`, didn't you?

Comment: @HerrSerker yes that is correct, copied exactly from made with love.